# How to replace the variable in Json format string in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following json format string as below.

```
json_data_string = "{\"size\":0,\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"time_zone\":\"+09:00\",\"gte\":\"2023-01-24T00:00:00.000Z\",\"lt\":\"2023-01-25T00:00:00.000Z\"}}},{\"term\":{\"serviceid.keyword\":{\"value\":\"430011397\"}}}]}},\"aggs\":{\"by_day\":{\"auto_date_histogram\":{\"field\":\"@timestamp\",\"minimum_interval\":\"minute\"},\"aggs\":{\"agg-type\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"nxlogtype.keyword\",\"size\":1000},\"aggs\":{\"my-sub-agg-name\":{\"avg\":{\"field\":\"size\"}}}}}}}}"
```

In this field, there is `gte` field which is the starting time.
I would like to put this value by variable, not by the constant string as shown above.

For example, I want to generate many json format string by using the `for-loop` as below.

```
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
d1 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-01 00:00:00', fmt)
d2 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-02 00:00:00', fmt)
minutesDiff = (d2 - d1).days * 24 * 60

for n in range(minutesDiff):
    print(json_data_string_variable.format(datetime.strptime(str(d1 + timedelta(minutes=n)),fmt)))
```

By using the iterative style, I think that I can generate the multiple json string but I don't have idea to insert variable format in the `json_data_string`. I have googled it and tried to use `{}` syntax in the `json_data_string` but it did not work.

How to achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the older modulo formatting. Replace the `gte` field with `%s`:

```
json_data_string = "{\"size\":0,\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"time_zone\":\"+09:00\",\"gte\":\"%s\",\"lt\":\"2023-01-25T00:00:00.000Z\"}}},{\"term\":{\"serviceid.keyword\":{\"value\":\"430011397\"}}}]}},\"aggs\":{\"by_day\":{\"auto_date_histogram\":{\"field\":\"@timestamp\",\"minimum_interval\":\"minute\"},\"aggs\":{\"agg-type\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"nxlogtype.keyword\",\"size\":1000},\"aggs\":{\"my-sub-agg-name\":{\"avg\":{\"field\":\"size\"}}}}}}}}"
```

Then use `%` to format the string

```
for n in range(minutesDiff):
    print(json_data_string % (datetime.strptime(str(d1 + timedelta(minutes=n)),fmt)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string representation of JSON to a Python dictionary. You can then access the 'gte' and 'lt' values as follows:

```
json_data_string = "{\"size\":0,\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"time_zone\":\"+09:00\",\"gte\":\"2023-01-24T00:00:00.000Z\",\"lt\":\"2023-01-25T00:00:00.000Z\"}}},{\"term\":{\"serviceid.keyword\":{\"value\":\"430011397\"}}}]}},\"aggs\":{\"by_day\":{\"auto_date_histogram\":{\"field\":\"@timestamp\",\"minimum_interval\":\"minute\"},\"aggs\":{\"agg-type\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"nxlogtype.keyword\",\"size\":1000},\"aggs\":{\"my-sub-agg-name\":{\"avg\":{\"field\":\"size\"}}}}}}}}"

j = json.loads(json_data_string)

timestamp = j['query']['bool']['must'][0]['range']['@timestamp']

gte = timestamp['gte']
lt = timestamp['lt']

print(gte, lt)
```

**Output:**

```
2023-01-24T00:00:00.000Z 2023-01-25T00:00:00.000Z
```